# Using slopes to find orthocentre of a triangle

Tags: triangles, coordinate-systems, slope

Let vertices of a triangle be $A(1,0)$, $B(-2,1)$, $C(5,2)$. Let orthocentre be $H(a,b)$. Slope of $AH=b/(a-1)$, slope of $BH = (b-1)/(a+2)$, slope of $CH = (b-2)/(a-5)$. I assumed $AH, BH, CH$ to be mutually perpendicular. Slopes of perpendicular lines have relation $p*q=-1$ where p and q are slopes of the lines.
Using the above relation I got $a^2+b^2-a-b-2=0$, $a^2+b^2-6a-2b+5=0$ and $a^2+b^2-3a-3b-8=0$. On solving the three equations i got $a=2$ and $b=-7$ which are the correct coordinates.
**Even though I took $AH$, $BH$, $CH$ to be mutually perpendicular, which is  completely false, I still got the right answer. How?**

Comment: Are you sure $(2, -7)$ is the orthocenter? I think this point is outside of the triangle.

Comment: Apparently you did a mistake in solving the system of quadratic equations, because $(2,-7)$ satisfies NONE of them.

Comment: @Vasya Orthocentre is indeed outside the triangle

Comment: @user376343 it is true now you mention it, but if you still subtract first two equations then the first and the last you get 7a+b=7 and 4a+2b=-6 which does satisfy the equation.

Comment: @ManavGoyal: $(2,-7)$ is not he solution of your system, double-check your work.

Comment: @Vasya I have rechecked it through different methods and the orthocentre of the given triangle is indeed (2,-7). If you found a diiferent solution, i would be more than happy to see it.

Comment: @Manav Goyal the idea to use slopes of orthogonal lines is correct. Just look for the paires of orthogonal lines or vectors - it is the (opposite) side of the triangle which is orthogonal to the height. So AH to BC etc.

Comment: The orthocenter is indeed $(2,-7)$, but what @Vasya is telling you is that the system of three equations in your question has no real solutions whatsoever. Moreover, $a=2$, $b=-7$ satisfies _none_ of them, even after correcting the sign error in the first one. This prompts the question: how exactly did you come up with this solution to the system of equations?